# Stopping a Android service in an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-service

I'm having trouble STOPPING the StimulationService , I'm not sure if i'm calling the stopservice method correctly from my activity. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

**Activity to start and stop Service**

```
     public class Stimulation extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  private static final String TAG = "StimulationActivity";
  Button buttonStart, buttonStop;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.someapp.Activities.R.layout.stimulation);

    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(com.someapp.Activities.R.id.ButtonStart);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(com.someapp.Activities.R.id.ButtonStop);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
    case com.someapp.Activities.R.id.ButtonStart:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting service");
      startService(new Intent(this, StimulationService.class));
      break;
    case com.someapp.Activities.R.id.ButtonStop:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping service");
      stopService(new Intent(this, StimulationService.class));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

}

**Service**

```
     public class StimulationService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "StimulationService";
private IOIO ioio_;
private DigitalOutput led       


private volatile IOIOThread ioio_thread_;

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

}

public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    ioio_thread_.stop();

}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    ioio_thread_ = new IOIOThread();
    ioio_thread_.start();

}

public void onStop(Intent intent, int stopid) {
    Log.d(TAG, "stop()");
    ioio_thread_ = null;
}


class IOIOThread extends Thread {
    private IOIO ioio_;
    private DigitalOutput led;

    /** Thread body. */
    public void run() {
        Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
        super.run();

        while (ioio_thread_ == thisThread) {
            ioio_ = IOIOFactory.create();
            try{
                Log.d(TAG, "Wait for IOIO Connection");
                ioio_.waitForConnect();
                Log.d(TAG, "IOIOConnected");

                while (true) {
                    intializePins();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Pins Intialized");
                    while(true){
                        led.write(false);
                        sleep(2000);
                        led.write(true);
                        sleep(2000);
                    }
                }

            }


            catch (ConnectionLostException e) {
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Hello", "Unexpected exception caught", e);
                ioio_.disconnect();
                break;
            } finally {
                try {
                    ioio_.waitForDisconnect();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: your code seems right to me. how do you say that the service doesn't get stop?

Comment: when I click to stop the service on the activity screen, the LED on the IOIO board continues to flash.

Comment: I see whats happening now.. its going to the onDestroy() function instead of the stop() function... any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked in LogCat to confirm that onDestroy() method of your service is called...?

Comment: a service doesnt have onStop method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: I used an abort() function which disconnected the IOIO device, and stopped the led blinking. However, The thread is still running in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity is OK. The problem is that the service is not killing the IOIOThread.
`Thread.stop()` is deprecated and will not do what you want anyway.
What you want is to call `ioio_.disconnect()` from the service's `onStop()` (through a method on your thread class), and then `join()` the thread.
See `AbstracIOIOActivity` as an example. With minor modifications it can be turned into `AbstractIOIOService`, and will enable you to leave you application-specific logic in a subclass.

Comment: Hey Ytai, I assume your Ytai Ben-Tsvi,Is it possible to power the IOIO device using the phone you have connected to it via the usb?

Comment: It's me indeed. The answer is no. IOIO is a USB host.

Answer (score 1):

First, as @Waqas notes, there is no `onStop()` method. There is an `onDestroy()` method, which will be called after `stopService()` is called.

Second, you are not stopping the background thread ever. Simply setting the `ioio_thread_` data member to `null` does not stop the thread. That thread will keep running forever. Please do not do this. If nothing else, use an `AtomicBoolean` instead of a hardwired `true` in your `while()` loop, and flip that `AtomicBoolean` to `false` in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, How would you implement an AtomicBoolean into this code?

Comment: @DavidFlanagan: Have it be a data member of the service. Set it to `true` before forking the thread. Examine it in your `while()` loop (replacing the hardcoded `true`). Set it to `false` in `onDestroy()`. Now, I just noticed your `ioio_thread_ == thisThread` check, which may solve the same problem, though you may need to declare `ioio_thread_` as `volatile`.